# Emacs change color for variables in java mode

Tags: java, emacs, font-lock

How to customize already defined color scheme in *emacs*. In my case, i have a `java mode`. I know how set background, or how set color to comments, but what should I do, to redefine color for variables only? In the best case I expect that I can move to needed region and redefine it with *magic* command...

Comment: ALT-X list-faces-display   from there you find the fonts("faces") and you can set them....

Comment: To see what face is being used on a particular character, move the point to that character and do `M-x describe-char` (there's also `M-x describe-face`, but that defaults to the "top level" face, whereas `describe-char` shows all of the layered faces.)

Comment: Wow, thanks you both! Really I surprised, that you're answered so fast and exactly what I've been wanted to hear. But @jpkotta 's answer is more suitable. So you could write answer. I will mark it as final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what face is used for a particular character, move the point to that character and do `M-x describe-char`.  It will tell you what faces are used, and from there you can customize them with `M-x customize-face` or with `(set-face-attribute 'the-face nil :some-parameter value)`.